# Progress Bar not appearing - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-progressbar

I kept getting an error in showing my progress bar.
Here is the code for XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in my kotlin code, I kept getting an error on showing my progress Bar

`OnCreate()`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

        init()
    }
```

`showRegisterLayout()` - the highlighted part is my error

```
private fun showRegisterLayout() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.DialogTheme)
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_register,null)

        val edt_first_name = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.edt_first_name) as TextInputEditText
        val edt_last_name = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.edt_last_name) as TextInputEditText
        val edt_phone_number = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.edt_phone_number) as TextInputEditText

        val btn_continue = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_register) as Button

        //set_data
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.phoneNumber != null &&
            !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.phoneNumber))
            edt_phone_number.setText(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.phoneNumber)

        //view
        builder.setView(itemView)
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()

        //Event
        btn_continue.setOnClickListener {
            if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edt_first_name.text.toString())){
            Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"Enter your First Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@setOnClickListener
            }
            else if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edt_last_name.text.toString())){
                Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"Enter your Last Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            else if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edt_phone_number.text.toString())){
                Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"Enter your Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            else
            {
                val model = DriverInfoModel()
                model.firstName = edt_first_name.text.toString()
                model.lastName = edt_last_name.text.toString()
                model.phoneNumber = edt_phone_number.text.toString()

                model.rating = 0.0

                driverInfoRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                    .setValue(model)
                    .addOnFailureListener{ e ->
                        Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,""+e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        dialog.dismiss()
                        progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        dialog.dismiss()
                        progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

`progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE` is my error the `progress_bar` it kept showing red. I tried fixing it but no progress. Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: You didn't initialize the `progress_bar` .. something like `val progress_bar = itemView.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_bar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using synthetic binding, make sure you've imported progress_bar from the correct xml layout file.

Otherwise initialise the progress_bar properly with findViewById.

I recommend using ViewBinding which is more safer.